# Find SKNode in specific subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, sprite-kit, sknode

I've set up a number of subviews to get different regions. I would like to track which nodes are located in specific regions. I have one subview that I use to limit the region for gesture recognizer (works perfectly)

so if the player lands in the subview (score100View) that was added to the view. I want to give the player 100 points.

in the update method i'm tracking the different player nodes via:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"playerOneNode" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {}];
```

I was thinking that I could search only in a specific view via something like

```
for (node in score100Region)\\the subview
 score += 100;
}
```

That however isn't allowed. (warning: collection expresion type uiview may not respond to countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:)

I've looked through some of the UIView docs (as well as sprite kit PG) and tried searching for answers but just can't seem to wrap my head around this issue.

Some other things I've thought would work would be getting the position and seeing if that position was contained in score100Region. But I'm unsure how to do that as well.

Thanks for taking the time!

James

Comment: Post more code for context. Note that you can only have one (working) SKView on iOS. Consider that nodes are children of a SKScene, but neither SKScene nor its children are UIView objects.

Comment: Hi @LearnCocos2D what code would be useful? I don't have anything that really applies to this problem as every way I've tried to do this has failed.    I use a different subview to limit the area where you can interact with the nodes via gesture recognizer (that works well).  Think of a dartboard - I want to get the nodes that land in the bullseye via a subview. I was thinking that the easiest way to assign user points would be a subview but there could be other ways I'm just not sure what that would be.

Comment: sknode has methods to determine node at point and point in node see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/containsPoint: